# Where is the Subversion global config file for the Slik SVN client for Windows?

Tags: windows, svn, slik

Does anyone know where the SVN global config file is for the Slik SVN client for Windows? Specifically 64 bit?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Mine is located here (Windows 7 64-bit):

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\config
```

Comment: Thanks that was the location.

Comment: I can not find it on my server. Why it is not created?

Comment: For Cygwin's build of Subversion, it's in ~/.subversion such as /home/SYSTEM/.subversion.

Answer (score 9):

It's usually located in `%APPDATA%\Subversion`.

Comment: FYI: Restart after a fresh install. The `%APPDATA%/Subversion` folder didn't exist until I did a reboot... There might be a cleaner way to do this -- maybe logging out/in.

Comment: The folder is created after you first start any svn client. no need to reboot.

Comment: I can not find it on my server. Why it is not created?

Comment: most likely on your server, the svn part runs as another user than the one you're logged in. So %APPDATA% points to your folder instead of the server-user folder. But you can figure out the path by replacing the username in the expanded %APPDATA% path.

Answer (score 4):

Paths:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Application Data\Subversion\  --Windows XP   
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Subversion  -- Vista / 7
```

In Windows, If you can't see the config file. You can open it (without extension) if you paste  the above selected path in your window explorer. And then will choose your IDE app.

Finally, you can read the README file located in the same route.

Comment: from the readme: global config:  %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Subversion\config user specific config:  %APPDATA%\Subversion\config

Answer (score 1):

Or here if using the "localsystem" account:
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Subversion

Credit to: [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/9325/where-can-i-find-data-stored-by-a-windows-service-running-as-local-system-accoun)

Answer (score 0):

In my case all pathes from the comments contain default empty config files and real service parameters were stored at the registry:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Clansoft\SVNService**