# How to use Beyond Compare 3 as external SVN (SlikSVN) merge and diff tool on Windows?

Tags: svn, mergetool, beyondcompare3, difftool, slik

I want to configure SVN command line client SlikSVN with Beyond Compare 3 as external diff and merge tool. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `Beyond Compare 3` folder to Windows `PATH`. If you don't know how [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6318188/1637178) - just replace `Python` path with `Beyond Compare 3` path.
2. In `Beyond Compare 3` folder create `bcomp-diff.bat` file:

   ```
   @ECHO OFF

   SET DIFF="bcomp.exe"

   SET LEFT=%6
   SET RIGHT=%7

   %DIFF% %LEFT% %RIGHT%
   ```
3. In `Beyond Compare 3` folder create `bcomp-merge.bat` file:

   ```
   @ECHO OFF

   SET DIFF3=BComp.exe

   SET BASE=%1
   SET THEIRS=%2
   SET MINE=%3
   SET MERGED=%4

   REM left MINE
   REM center BASE
   REM right THEIRS
   %DIFF3% %MINE% %THEIRS% %BASE% %MERGED%
   ```
4. Now we need to edit `SlikSVN` config file. On Windows 7 it is located in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Subversion` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6310641/1637178)). Just paste this into Windows Explorer address bar and edit `config` file.

   In `[helpers]` section of `config` file add/modify as below:

   ```
   diff-cmd = bcomp-diff.bat
   merge-tool-cmd = bcomp-merge.bat
   ```
5. Restart `cmd.exe` so that `PATH` windows variable will be reloaded.
6. You're done! Try `svn diff` inside your repository and it should run `Beyond Compare 3`.

I've made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jan-swiecki/7164191) with above batch files.

*Batch files are based on [this website](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html).*