# Subversion ignores merge-tool-cmd option

Tags: svn, merge, beyondcompare

I have set up Beyond Compare 3 as a merge tool in Subversion. I have followed all the steps outlined [here (BeyondCompare documentation)](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs) and [here (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602729/how-to-use-beyond-compare-3-as-external-svn-sliksvn-merge-and-diff-tool-on-win) and [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html).

In particular, I have verified that:

- `merge-tool-cmd` points to a batch file.
- That batch file works when I run it manually with four parameters.
- `diff-tool-cmd` points to another batch file, and that one works. (`svn diff` uses it correctly.)

Yet when I run `svn resolve` and tell it to `m`erge, I just get the useless command-line merge thingie, not BeyondCompare.

What am I doing wrong?